# How to add a ssh key to remote server?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys

In my VPS, run `ssh-add -l` and it returns: `The agent has no identities.`
but I have run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'` previously

I then run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
it returns `@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys' are too open.
It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.`

and `ssh git@github.com` still get report `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: Did you add your public key to GitHub? Are you adding your ***private key*** with `ssh-add`? Also, the error message says that the user permissions on your keys are too open, you need to restrict read access to just yourself using `chmod 700`, or something like that.

Comment: Change permissions on your authorized key file (`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`), then see if that resolves the issue. Other than that I would verify that your cat command is doing what you expect.

Comment: after sorting this mess out, you might be interested in ssh agent forwarding `ssh -A`

Comment: I don't understand why this question would be voted down. After googling around, I didn't solve the problem at all. Finally I add pub key of remote server to GitHub instead.

Answer (score 20):

The currently most up voted answer is plainly wrong as it fails to understand the question. OP is asking how to authorize a key on a remote server, not how to add a key to your local ssh-agent.

To add a key to a remote server use the [`ssh-copy-id`](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id) command from your local PC:

```
ssh-copy-id -i path/to/key.pub username@remoteHost
```

This adds the public key located at `path/to/key.pub` with the correct permission to the server at `remoteHost` using `username` as login name. Note that this also seems to require the private key next to the public key (the `path/to/key` file in this example).

Answer (score 6):

To add your ssh-key to your ssh-agent you have to add it with:

```
ssh-add
```

After that ensure your key is added:

```
ssh-add -l
```

To fix your permission problem try:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Run these in the server?

Comment: Ask yourself where your ssh-agent is running... you're right on your client. ;)

Comment: I run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and get `Enter passphrase for /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys:`. But I do not specify a passphrase when creating the ssh in my local machine. What is the problem?

Comment: Late but may help someone. Its a good idea to reboot the server for new keys to be recognised.

Comment: Please add a line that clarifies to run this on the server. Would be also great do discuss, why `ssh-copy-id` is not a better solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use `pssh` utility (Paralell SSH Tools, see [Github repo](https://github.com/lilydjwg/pssh)).

Create a file with all the hostnames you want to add, then run:

```
pssh -h [hostsfile] -P 'echo "sshkeystringBLARG etc..." >> /home/[user]/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

You can modify the command accordingly.

Comment: Ah, overshot the answer. Google simple stuff like this, or search stackoverflow. This question's been answered a thousand times already.